# Область видимости переменных в Java Android

Tags: android, java, база-данных

Всем привет.

Создаю подключение к базе:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        DB_Interface connect_to_DB = new DB_Interface(MainActivity.this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = connect_to_DB.getWritableDatabase();

        }
```

Описываю интерфейс нажатия кнопки ниже:

```
OnClickListener click = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            String first_name = "Дудников";
            cv.put("name", first_name);
            long rowID = db.insert("list_student", null, cv);
            connect_to_DB.close();
        }
    };
```

Не видит `db` и `connect_to_DB` в первом коде. Я хотел, чтобы при создании приложения интерфейс базы создался, а далее я уже работал с базой - редактировал, удалял и т. д. Но получается, что надо каждый раз подключаться к базе, т.е. я нажал кнопку, подключился к базе. И делать так каждый раз?! Разве это правильно так дергать базу? Открывать-закрывать?

Comment: Сделайте полем класса. И коннект в onResume перенесите.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы создаете переменную db внутри тела функции  `onCreate`, за пределами которого она ни  в коем случае не будет видна. Вынесите обьявление переменной  `SQLiteDatabase db`; в класс (`Activity`?), как его поле, и инициализируйте ее и `onCreate`.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы даже кое-что добавил. Если вам нужно постоянное подключение к базе на всех активити и фграментах, вам нужэно вынести код в Application class. Тогда подключение будет выполнено 1 раз за весь код, при старте приложения. В текущей реализации, вам на каждом экране придется подключаться к базе. Смотрите пример с firebase.

Создаете класс и наследуете его от android.app.Application. Он будет вызван 1 раз при старте приложения:

```
 public class Application extends android.app.Application {
    private static FirebaseDbHelper fdbHelper;

    public static FirebaseDbHelper getFdbHelper(){
        return fdbHelper;
    }

    public static FirebaseInstanceId getInstanceId(){ return fdbHelper.getInstanceID(); }

    public static FirebaseAuth getAuth(){
        return fdbHelper.getFirebaseAuth();
    }

    public static FirebaseAuth getAuthInstance(){ return fdbHelper.getAuthInstance(); }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        FirebaseApp.getInstance().setAutomaticResourceManagementEnabled(true);
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(false);
        fdbHelper = new FirebaseDbHelper(this, GLOBAL_MODE);
        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
        Fresco.initialize(getApplicationContext());
//        System.setProperty("rx.unsafe-disable", "True");
    }

    public static void changeSelectedDB(Context context, int mode){
        fdbHelper = new FirebaseDbHelper(context, mode);
    }
}
```

Далее вы можете обращаться к этой переменной из любого участка программы. Я например делаю отлдельную обертку для fragment и activity, чтобы уменьшить дублирование кода. Ниже мой родительский класс для всех фрагментов работающих с базой данных:

```
 public class FirebaseSupportFragment extends Fragment  implements Constants{
    protected FirebaseDbHelper fdbHelper;
    protected FirebaseAuth auth;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        fdbHelper = Application.getFdbHelper();
        auth = Application.getAuth();
    }
}
```

В случае, если подключение к базе должно быть постоянным, советую вам выполнить реализацию подобным образом. Удачи!